# Margin way to big

Tags: html, css, margin

Currently I'm building a website and I have a service page where every service has is own box, now on big screens I have 3 of those boxes next to each other.

But the next row of 3 boxes is way to far away of the top ones, changing the `margin-top` won't help.

It happened when I edited the `height` of the div containing all of the boxes, I don't understand why that would change the `margins`.

Code:

```css
.diensten {
  margin-top: 90px;
  height: 4000px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.diensten>div {
  margin: 90px 45px 0;
}

#dienst1 {
  margin-top: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#dienst2 {
  margin-top: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#dienst3 {
  margin-top: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#dienst4 {
  margin-top: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#dienst5 {
  margin-top: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#dienst6 {
  margin-top: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#dienst7 {
  margin-top: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#dienst8 {
  margin-top: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#dienst9 {
  margin-top: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="diensten">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Al onze diensten op een rijtje</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="dienst1">
    <h2>Ontruimingsoefening</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen diverse ontruimingsoefeningen die afgestemd zijn op zorginstellingen, onderwijsinstellingen, kinderdagverblijven, horecagelegenheden en detailhandel. De ontruimingsoefeningen kunnen zowel theoretisch (Table Top) als praktisch toegepast
      worden waarbij wij gebruik maken van professionele hulpmiddelen om de ontruimingsoefening zo realistisch mogelijk te maken.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2670.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst2">
    <h2>Beheer brandmeldinstallatie</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen de verplichte maandelijkse en viermaandelijkse beheerderstaken van de brandmeldinstallatie conform NEN 2654 op professionele wijze voor zorginstellingen, onderwijsinstellingen, kinderdagverblijven, horecagelegenheden, kantoorgebouwen
      en detailhandel. Het onderhoud van de brandmeldinstallatie bestaat uit het testen van de doormelding naar de brandweer van automatische rookmelders en handbrandmelders, het testen van de doormelding van storingen aan de brandmeldinstallatie, een
      visuele controle van de aangesloten componenten, het bijwerken en onderhouden van het logboek.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2704.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst3">
    <h2>Camerabeveiliging</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw camera beveiliging. Registratie wat er in en rond uw pand gebeurt, het kan door middel van camera’s welke worden geprojecteerd in overleg, zodat de verzochte beelden kunnen worden opgeslagen op een harddisk recorder. Camera’s zijn
      er in diverse types. Voor de nachtelijke situatie kunnen er lampen worden geplaatst, ook zijn er camera’s welke in het donker automatisch overschakelen naar zwart-wit en doormiddel van ingebouwde infrarood verlichting nog uitstekend beeld geven.
      Tevens is het koppelen van camerabeelden met een Particuliere Alarmcentrale mogelijk.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/Camerabeveiliging.jpg" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst4">
    <h2>Legionellabeheer</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen het legionellabeheer vanuit het legionellabeheersplan voor zorginstellingen, sportverenigingen, hotels en indien van toepassing voor onderwijsinstellingen. De beheerderstaken bestaan onder andere uit het beheer van het logboek, de maandelijkse
      temperatuurmeting van risico tappunten, de halfjaarlijkse en jaarlijkse bemonstering volgens het beheersplan, preparatie maatregelen n.a.v. een besmetting, preventief spoelen/verversen en thermisch desinfecteren volgens het legionella beheersplan.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/Legionellabeheer.jpg" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst5">
    <h2>Alarmsysteem</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw alarmsysteem. Steeds meer bedrijven en huishoudens in Nederland krijgen te maken met ongewenst bezoek op elk denkbaar tijdstip van de dag. Bescherming van uw bedrijf of huis en inboedel d.m.v. elektronische systemen is tegenwoordig
      geen overbodige luxe, maar is een noodzakelijk kwaad is geworden. Ook installeren wij brand en ontruimings installaties welke gecertificeerd kunnen worden opgeleverd. </p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2693.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst6">
    <h2>BHV trainingen</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw BHV trainingen. Sinds 1994 eist de Arbowet dat elke werkgever de veiligheid van medewerkers, klanten en andere aanwezigen kan garanderen door het aanstellen van één of meerdere BHVer(s). Het aanstellen van een Bedrijfshulpverlener
      helpt de veiligheid in een bedrijf te vergroten. Een BHV-er is opgeleid en verantwoordelijk voor het verlenen van Eerste Hulp, het bestrijden van een beginnende brand en het begeleiden van een ontruiming.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2699.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst7">
    <h2>Veiligheidscheck</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen een maandelijkse woningschouw van gebouwen en adviseren u over de wettelijke normen die toegepast moeten worden voor de verschillende overheidsinstanties. Uitvoer van risico-inventarisatie en evaluatie RI&E, keuren en verkopen van blusmiddelen,
      keuren en verkoop van noodverlichting, verzorging en verkoop van BHV koffers en overige veiligheidsmiddelen behoord tot de mogelijkheden.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="dienst8">
    <h2>Toegangscontrole</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw toegangscontrole. Doordat bedrijven goed zijn beveiligd tegen inbraak slaat de criminaliteit overdag tijdens openingstijden toe, het toepassen van toegangscontrole is daardoor enorm groeiend. Afhankelijk van de individuele toepassingswens
      wordt een toegangscontrole systeem opgebouwd. De toepassingen zijn divers van standalone op één deur tot een netwerk van deuren op verschillende locaties die centraal gecontroleerd kan worden. Elektronische cilinders kunnen worden gemonteerd op
      uw bestaande cilinder, nooit meer sleutels kwijt alleen de toegangspas of tac uitprogrammeren en het sleutelplan is weer sluitend.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="dienst9">
    <h2>Inspectie brandmeldinstallatie</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw inspecties. Bij de inspectie processen wordt vastgesteld of het brandbeveiligingssysteem voldoet aan de afgeleide doelstellingen. De inspectie bestaat uit administratieve, visuele en functionele waarnemingen conform NEN 2575. In de
      uitgangspunten zijn de afstemming van de techniek op de interne en externe alarmorganisatie en de bouwkundige maatregelen die de brandveiligheid waarborgt. We gaan in Nederland steeds bewuster om met brandveiligheid en inspecties. De regels en het
      toezicht op naleving van de regels zijn de laatste jaren verder aangescherpt (Bouwbesluit 2012). Brandveiligheid is een zeer belangrijk aspect. Zo heeft de overheid voor de meeste installaties brandveiligheid voorwaarden gesteld voor het verlenen
      van een bouw- of milieuvergunning. Voor installaties die worden aangebracht op wens van een gebruiker/eigenaar worden door verzekeraars brandveiligheidvoorwaarden gesteld als onderdeel van een verzekeringscontract. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't repeat yourself (DRI)](https://www.google.com/search?q=don't%20repeat%20yourself%20css), if you have the exact same properties for siblings elements then use a class or use the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `>`  (or even [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)) instead using IDs for each one.

and the problem is `height:4000px` so remove it.

**Note:** you had `margin-top:300px` in each ID, and AFAIK you just want `margin-top:90px` and

```css
.diensten {
  margin-top: 90px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.diensten>div {
  margin: 90px 45px 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="diensten">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Al onze diensten op een rijtje</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="dienst1">
    <h2>Ontruimingsoefening</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen diverse ontruimingsoefeningen die afgestemd zijn op zorginstellingen, onderwijsinstellingen, kinderdagverblijven, horecagelegenheden en detailhandel. De ontruimingsoefeningen kunnen zowel theoretisch (Table Top) als praktisch toegepast
      worden waarbij wij gebruik maken van professionele hulpmiddelen om de ontruimingsoefening zo realistisch mogelijk te maken.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2670.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst2">
    <h2>Beheer brandmeldinstallatie</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen de verplichte maandelijkse en viermaandelijkse beheerderstaken van de brandmeldinstallatie conform NEN 2654 op professionele wijze voor zorginstellingen, onderwijsinstellingen, kinderdagverblijven, horecagelegenheden, kantoorgebouwen
      en detailhandel. Het onderhoud van de brandmeldinstallatie bestaat uit het testen van de doormelding naar de brandweer van automatische rookmelders en handbrandmelders, het testen van de doormelding van storingen aan de brandmeldinstallatie, een
      visuele controle van de aangesloten componenten, het bijwerken en onderhouden van het logboek.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2704.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst3">
    <h2>Camerabeveiliging</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw camera beveiliging. Registratie wat er in en rond uw pand gebeurt, het kan door middel van camera’s welke worden geprojecteerd in overleg, zodat de verzochte beelden kunnen worden opgeslagen op een harddisk recorder. Camera’s zijn
      er in diverse types. Voor de nachtelijke situatie kunnen er lampen worden geplaatst, ook zijn er camera’s welke in het donker automatisch overschakelen naar zwart-wit en doormiddel van ingebouwde infrarood verlichting nog uitstekend beeld geven.
      Tevens is het koppelen van camerabeelden met een Particuliere Alarmcentrale mogelijk.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/Camerabeveiliging.jpg" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst4">
    <h2>Legionellabeheer</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen het legionellabeheer vanuit het legionellabeheersplan voor zorginstellingen, sportverenigingen, hotels en indien van toepassing voor onderwijsinstellingen. De beheerderstaken bestaan onder andere uit het beheer van het logboek, de maandelijkse
      temperatuurmeting van risico tappunten, de halfjaarlijkse en jaarlijkse bemonstering volgens het beheersplan, preparatie maatregelen n.a.v. een besmetting, preventief spoelen/verversen en thermisch desinfecteren volgens het legionella beheersplan.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/Legionellabeheer.jpg" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst5">
    <h2>Alarmsysteem</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw alarmsysteem. Steeds meer bedrijven en huishoudens in Nederland krijgen te maken met ongewenst bezoek op elk denkbaar tijdstip van de dag. Bescherming van uw bedrijf of huis en inboedel d.m.v. elektronische systemen is tegenwoordig
      geen overbodige luxe, maar is een noodzakelijk kwaad is geworden. Ook installeren wij brand en ontruimings installaties welke gecertificeerd kunnen worden opgeleverd. </p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2693.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst6">
    <h2>BHV trainingen</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw BHV trainingen. Sinds 1994 eist de Arbowet dat elke werkgever de veiligheid van medewerkers, klanten en andere aanwezigen kan garanderen door het aanstellen van één of meerdere BHVer(s). Het aanstellen van een Bedrijfshulpverlener
      helpt de veiligheid in een bedrijf te vergroten. Een BHV-er is opgeleid en verantwoordelijk voor het verlenen van Eerste Hulp, het bestrijden van een beginnende brand en het begeleiden van een ontruiming.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2699.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst7">
    <h2>Veiligheidscheck</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen een maandelijkse woningschouw van gebouwen en adviseren u over de wettelijke normen die toegepast moeten worden voor de verschillende overheidsinstanties. Uitvoer van risico-inventarisatie en evaluatie RI&E, keuren en verkopen van blusmiddelen,
      keuren en verkoop van noodverlichting, verzorging en verkoop van BHV koffers en overige veiligheidsmiddelen behoord tot de mogelijkheden.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="dienst8">
    <h2>Toegangscontrole</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw toegangscontrole. Doordat bedrijven goed zijn beveiligd tegen inbraak slaat de criminaliteit overdag tijdens openingstijden toe, het toepassen van toegangscontrole is daardoor enorm groeiend. Afhankelijk van de individuele toepassingswens
      wordt een toegangscontrole systeem opgebouwd. De toepassingen zijn divers van standalone op één deur tot een netwerk van deuren op verschillende locaties die centraal gecontroleerd kan worden. Elektronische cilinders kunnen worden gemonteerd op
      uw bestaande cilinder, nooit meer sleutels kwijt alleen de toegangspas of tac uitprogrammeren en het sleutelplan is weer sluitend.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="dienst9">
    <h2>Inspectie brandmeldinstallatie</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw inspecties. Bij de inspectie processen wordt vastgesteld of het brandbeveiligingssysteem voldoet aan de afgeleide doelstellingen. De inspectie bestaat uit administratieve, visuele en functionele waarnemingen conform NEN 2575. In de
      uitgangspunten zijn de afstemming van de techniek op de interne en externe alarmorganisatie en de bouwkundige maatregelen die de brandveiligheid waarborgt. We gaan in Nederland steeds bewuster om met brandveiligheid en inspecties. De regels en het
      toezicht op naleving van de regels zijn de laatste jaren verder aangescherpt (Bouwbesluit 2012). Brandveiligheid is een zeer belangrijk aspect. Zo heeft de overheid voor de meeste installaties brandveiligheid voorwaarden gesteld voor het verlenen
      van een bouw- of milieuvergunning. Voor installaties die worden aangebracht op wens van een gebruiker/eigenaar worden door verzekeraars brandveiligheidvoorwaarden gesteld als onderdeel van een verzekeringscontract. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st**. use `height: 100%;` instead of `height: 4000px;`

**2nd**. if you need use `dienst1`, `dienst2`, `dienst3` etc. and they have the same css. just use attribute selector in css `[id^="dienst"] {...}` you can read more here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

**3rd**. you don't need `.diensten>div {...}` that are targeting all `divs` and you are using ids to target the same `divs`. remove `.diensten>div {...}` or remove the id selector.

**4th**. I added a header wrapper to your header.

```css
.diensten {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

[id^="dienst"] {
  margin: 45px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px #000;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inine-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="diensten">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Al onze diensten op een rijtje</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="dienst1">
    <h2>Ontruimingsoefening</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen diverse ontruimingsoefeningen die afgestemd zijn op zorginstellingen, onderwijsinstellingen, kinderdagverblijven, horecagelegenheden en detailhandel. De ontruimingsoefeningen kunnen zowel theoretisch (Table Top) als praktisch toegepast
      worden waarbij wij gebruik maken van professionele hulpmiddelen om de ontruimingsoefening zo realistisch mogelijk te maken.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2670.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst2">
    <h2>Beheer brandmeldinstallatie</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen de verplichte maandelijkse en viermaandelijkse beheerderstaken van de brandmeldinstallatie conform NEN 2654 op professionele wijze voor zorginstellingen, onderwijsinstellingen, kinderdagverblijven, horecagelegenheden, kantoorgebouwen
      en detailhandel. Het onderhoud van de brandmeldinstallatie bestaat uit het testen van de doormelding naar de brandweer van automatische rookmelders en handbrandmelders, het testen van de doormelding van storingen aan de brandmeldinstallatie, een
      visuele controle van de aangesloten componenten, het bijwerken en onderhouden van het logboek.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2704.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst3">
    <h2>Camerabeveiliging</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw camera beveiliging. Registratie wat er in en rond uw pand gebeurt, het kan door middel van camera’s welke worden geprojecteerd in overleg, zodat de verzochte beelden kunnen worden opgeslagen op een harddisk recorder. Camera’s zijn
      er in diverse types. Voor de nachtelijke situatie kunnen er lampen worden geplaatst, ook zijn er camera’s welke in het donker automatisch overschakelen naar zwart-wit en doormiddel van ingebouwde infrarood verlichting nog uitstekend beeld geven.
      Tevens is het koppelen van camerabeelden met een Particuliere Alarmcentrale mogelijk.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/Camerabeveiliging.jpg" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst4">
    <h2>Legionellabeheer</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen het legionellabeheer vanuit het legionellabeheersplan voor zorginstellingen, sportverenigingen, hotels en indien van toepassing voor onderwijsinstellingen. De beheerderstaken bestaan onder andere uit het beheer van het logboek, de maandelijkse
      temperatuurmeting van risico tappunten, de halfjaarlijkse en jaarlijkse bemonstering volgens het beheersplan, preparatie maatregelen n.a.v. een besmetting, preventief spoelen/verversen en thermisch desinfecteren volgens het legionella beheersplan.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/Legionellabeheer.jpg" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst5">
    <h2>Alarmsysteem</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw alarmsysteem. Steeds meer bedrijven en huishoudens in Nederland krijgen te maken met ongewenst bezoek op elk denkbaar tijdstip van de dag. Bescherming van uw bedrijf of huis en inboedel d.m.v. elektronische systemen is tegenwoordig
      geen overbodige luxe, maar is een noodzakelijk kwaad is geworden. Ook installeren wij brand en ontruimings installaties welke gecertificeerd kunnen worden opgeleverd. </p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2693.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst6">
    <h2>BHV trainingen</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw BHV trainingen. Sinds 1994 eist de Arbowet dat elke werkgever de veiligheid van medewerkers, klanten en andere aanwezigen kan garanderen door het aanstellen van één of meerdere BHVer(s). Het aanstellen van een Bedrijfshulpverlener
      helpt de veiligheid in een bedrijf te vergroten. Een BHV-er is opgeleid en verantwoordelijk voor het verlenen van Eerste Hulp, het bestrijden van een beginnende brand en het begeleiden van een ontruiming.</p>
    <img src="Foto's/IMG_2699.JPG" data-tilt data-tilt-max="30" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="900">
  </div>

  <div id="dienst7">
    <h2>Veiligheidscheck</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen een maandelijkse woningschouw van gebouwen en adviseren u over de wettelijke normen die toegepast moeten worden voor de verschillende overheidsinstanties. Uitvoer van risico-inventarisatie en evaluatie RI&E, keuren en verkopen van blusmiddelen,
      keuren en verkoop van noodverlichting, verzorging en verkoop van BHV koffers en overige veiligheidsmiddelen behoord tot de mogelijkheden.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="dienst8">
    <h2>Toegangscontrole</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw toegangscontrole. Doordat bedrijven goed zijn beveiligd tegen inbraak slaat de criminaliteit overdag tijdens openingstijden toe, het toepassen van toegangscontrole is daardoor enorm groeiend. Afhankelijk van de individuele toepassingswens
      wordt een toegangscontrole systeem opgebouwd. De toepassingen zijn divers van standalone op één deur tot een netwerk van deuren op verschillende locaties die centraal gecontroleerd kan worden. Elektronische cilinders kunnen worden gemonteerd op
      uw bestaande cilinder, nooit meer sleutels kwijt alleen de toegangspas of tac uitprogrammeren en het sleutelplan is weer sluitend.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="dienst9">
    <h2>Inspectie brandmeldinstallatie</h2>
    <p>Wij verzorgen uw inspecties. Bij de inspectie processen wordt vastgesteld of het brandbeveiligingssysteem voldoet aan de afgeleide doelstellingen. De inspectie bestaat uit administratieve, visuele en functionele waarnemingen conform NEN 2575. In de
      uitgangspunten zijn de afstemming van de techniek op de interne en externe alarmorganisatie en de bouwkundige maatregelen die de brandveiligheid waarborgt. We gaan in Nederland steeds bewuster om met brandveiligheid en inspecties. De regels en het
      toezicht op naleving van de regels zijn de laatste jaren verder aangescherpt (Bouwbesluit 2012). Brandveiligheid is een zeer belangrijk aspect. Zo heeft de overheid voor de meeste installaties brandveiligheid voorwaarden gesteld voor het verlenen
      van een bouw- of milieuvergunning. Voor installaties die worden aangebracht op wens van een gebruiker/eigenaar worden door verzekeraars brandveiligheidvoorwaarden gesteld als onderdeel van een verzekeringscontract. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```